# How do I resolve "name 'aiplatform' is not defined" error when running predictions from a notebook?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

Running predictions from a notebook failing with

```
'NameError: name 'aiplatform' is not defined'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install and import the aiplatform SDK

Here is the [installation guide](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/start/client-libraries#python)
Import it like this:

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform
```

Here is an [example notebook](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/main/notebooks/official/automl/automl-tabular-classification.ipynb)